# Sort List with date and time

Tags: android

Need to sort ListView by date and time. There are multiple Voller requests, both set on one ListView (Volley Second request) show below (Volley request one). and
only one ArrayList is used,(ArrayList newsItemsList;) Need to sort the list with date and time. How to use a comparator? Or is there is any other way to do this? since all set on one list so need to sort in the adapter
Thanks in advance.

date format (Sat, 16 Jun 2018 09:21:37)

```
ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItemsList;
 ListView list;
NewsAdaptor adapter;
```

MainActivity

```
 newsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
 list  = (ListView)view. findViewById(R.id.listview);

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("https://www.express.pk/feed/", new Response.Listener <String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse ( String response ) {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
        Elements itemElements = document.getElementsByTag("item");
        for (int i = 0; i < itemElements.size(); i++) {
            Element item = itemElements.get(i);
            String title = rem(item.child(0).text());
            String pubDate =rem( item.child(4).text()) ;


            NewItem newitem = new NewItem();
            newsItem.setDate(item.child(3).text());
                newsItem.setTitle(item.child(2).text())
            newItemsList.add(newitem);}



   adapter = new MyAdaptor(getContext(), newItemsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse ( VolleyError error ) {
    }
});
requestQueue2.add(stringRequest2);

//second Request
 RequestQueue requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest("https://www.express.pk/feed/", new Response.Listener <String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse ( String response ) {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
        Elements itemElements = document.getElementsByTag("item");
        for (int i = 0; i < itemElements.size(); i++) {
            Element item = itemElements.get(i);
            String title = rem(item.child(0).text());
            String pubDate =rem( item.child(4).text()) ;


            NewItem newitem = new NewItem();
            newsItem.setDate(item.child(3).text());
                newsItem.setTitle(item.child(2).text())
            newItemsList.add(newitem);}



   adapter = new MyAdaptor(getContext(), newItemsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse ( VolleyError error ) {
    }
});
requestQueue2.add(stringRequest2);
```

NewsItem.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class NewsItem implements Serializable {

String title;
String date;

public String getTitle () {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle ( String title ) {
    this.title = title;
}



public String getDate () {
    return date;
}

public void setDate ( String date ) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
  }
```

}

NewsAdapter

```
public class NewsAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<NewsItem> newsList;

public NewsAdaptor ( Context context, ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsList = newsList;
}

@Override
public int getCount () {
    return newsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem ( int position ) {
    return newsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId ( int position ) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView=View.inflate(context, R.layout.newsitemlist_layout,null);
    }
    NewsItem currentNews = newsList.get(position);

    TextView tvtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1id);
    TextView tvdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pubDateid);

    tvtitle.setText(currentNews.title);
    tvdate.setText(currentNews.date);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

newsitemlist_layout.xml

```
     <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1id"
    android:layout_width="237dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
/>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:layout_width="237dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use comparator and sort.

Comment: I know. I ask because I don't know how and where   can u edit my code or give some idea

Comment: Why are you making the same request twice?

Comment: it just samples multiple requests in the same way for multiple data than need sort this data with date and time like news are movies data

Comment: Use a date-time class like for instance `Instant` for your dates and times rather than a string. It’s much more convenient for processing, not least for sorting. And you can always format into a string when you need to display the date and time for a user.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your list before setting it to the adapter.

```
   private void sort(ArrayList<NewsItem> itemList) {
            Collections.sort(itemList, new Comparator<NewsItem>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(NewsItem o1, NewsItem o2) {
                    return o1.dateInMilliSec < o2.dateInMilliSec ? -1 :
                            o1.dateInMilliSec > o2.dateInMilliSec ? 1 : 0;
                }
            });
        }


public class NewsItem implements Serializable {

    String title;
    String date;
    long dateInMilliSec;

    private long getDateInMilliSec() {
        return dateInMilliSec;
    }

    private void setDateInMilliSec(long dateInMilliSec) {
        this.dateInMilliSec = dateInMilliSec;

    }




    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
        try {
            Date dateObj = sdf.parse(date);
            setDateInMilliSec(dateObj.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s so outdated and so troublesome. Instead use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks for the info but DateTimeFormatter is available from API level 26 in Android..

Comment: I should consider that a good piece of info to include: the better `DateTimeFormatter` is available from API level 26. I should like to add that `java.time` has been backported and hence can be used on lower API levels too. Add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First add Method Return LocalDateTime From String to NewsItem class using :

```
class NewsItem implements Serializable {

    String title;
    String date;

    public String getTitle () {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle ( String title ) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime(){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        return LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(date));
    }

    public String getDate () {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate ( String date ) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

And Sort ArrayList Before Send Him To Adapter Using :

```
Collections.sort(newsItemsList, (o1, o2) -> {
            return o1.getDateTime().compareTo(o2.getDateTime());
        });
```

Comment: Whare sort ArrayList

Comment: before calling: adapter = new MyAdaptor(getContext(), newItemsList);

Comment: I tray but error     java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Mon, 25 Jun 2018 15:47:01 ' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 25

Comment: It seems you’ve got a space after the seconds in your string. If you store `LocalDateTime` instead of string it will not happen.

Comment: i 've tested in this  date format "Sat, 16 Jun 2018 09:21:38",  it work fine, Does All Your dates in this format ?